# How to define a Unique Key Constraint that is composed of all columns in the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a shorthand similar to the wildcard symbol that allows me to define a unique key by which every column participates in the key?  I'm using Postgres and I have a 30+ column table. Part of me thinks it's silly that I have to type out every single column name that will participate in the unique key.

I also think it would be awesome to not have to update the unique key if columns were added in the future.

I'm new to SQL, so please take it easy if this is a stupid question.

Comment: I don't think this is a stupid question. However, I do think this is a very unusual requirement. As such, I doubt there are any shortcuts.

Comment: Why do you need each column to be unique?

Comment: It is definitely not required to do so. For simplicity, you can use serial column.

Comment: Having a table with 30 columns where all make up the primary key sure sounds like a bad design.

Comment: @Nick Binnet: If the combination of 30 columns is supposed to be unique, an ID number alone can't enforce that requirement. Only a UNIQUE constraint on those 30 columns can enforce that requirement.

Comment: @Oded it's a table for keeping track of different performance testing scenarios.  Class name, method name, and assorted variables values (null if not used) and associated variable parameter ordinals makes for a unique test scenario id.  Then the primary key (a serial int) from the test scenario can be used to collect information from a performance results table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: There is a primary key column that is a serial int.  Defining the unique constraint is just to keep from there being repeat entries.  I could do it on the java end, but I was just curious as to how I might do it in SQL.  If you could point me to documentation or design recommendations as to why this is bad design I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @DavisRunning: having a unique constraint on 30 columns still seems odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No maintenance-free shortcut. But right-click the table name in pgAdminIII, then select "Scripts", then "SELECT script". That will open a SQL window with a SELECT statement with every column listed and correctly quoted, if quotes are necessary.

I've been working on SQL database since the mid 1980s. I'm pretty sure I've never seen a table that had that many columns in a key. You might want to post the DDL for some more experienced eyes to evaluate.

DDL stands for Data Definition Language. It's the CREATE TABLE statement that defines the table. In pgAdminIII, right-click a table name, select "Scripts", then "CREATE script". pgAdminIII will open a SQL window with the CREATE TABLE statement (the DDL) in it. Copy it, edit your original question (or ask a new question), and paste that in.

Comment: Lol, if you've been rocking this out since the 1980s and you've never seen a table design like this, I may be doing something pretty wonky.  I'm going to give the SELECT script a try.  Is that something like putting in a Trigger function?  What is DDL?

Comment: The SELECT script is nothing like a trigger. It just selects all the rows in the table. What it does *for your* is it includes all the column names, so you don't have to type them. Copy and paste them into whatever you like.